# Header customization in a fluid layout

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I am doing this portfolio project and I am getting a bit confused.

I want my header div to stick on top and to be with a width of 100% of the page. But in the code it is interfering with the wrapper and I cant manage to find the problem. Here is the code:

```
<header class="wrapper clearfix">

    <div id="banner">        
        <div id="logo"><a href="basic.html"><img src="images/web.png" alt="logo"></a></div> 
    </div>

    <!-- main navigation -->
    <nav id="topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-toggle">Menu</div>  
        <ul class="srt-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">
            <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
        </ul>     
    </nav><!-- end main navigation -->
</header>
```

and here is the css:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 92%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If i remove .wrapper from the header class. the banner sticks at the top and width is 100%, but then I can't manage to put the logo and menu in the correct alignment and they just stick at left and right. I want them to be aligned vertically with the other content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the .wrapper class as you did, but add an .inner 'div' that wraps your banner and nav, and give it the width:92% and margin:0 auto;.... like so:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div id="banner">        
            <div id="logo"><a href="basic.html"><img src="images/web.png" alt="logo"></a></div> 
        </div>

        <!-- main navigation -->
        <nav id="topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-toggle">Menu</div>  
            <ul class="srt-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">
            <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
                      <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
                                          <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>
                                                    <li class="current"><a href="basic.html">Home page</a></li>

        </ul>     
        </nav><!-- end main navigation -->
    </div>
</header>
```